# Create aurora db instance via rds in python

Tags: python, amazon-rds, aws-cli, amazon-aurora

I'm very confused as to how to create a new aurora db instance using the boto3 api. From what I understand, in order to make a new aurora db instance, i first need to create a cluster, then once i make a cluster I can make an instance. However, how does the instance know the cluster is already created? All in all I'm very lost, so any further clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You pass in the cluster name using the `DBClusterIdentifier`.

Here's a quick and dirty showing it's usage:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3

rds = boto3.client('rds')

cpg = rds.create_db_cluster_parameter_group(
    DBClusterParameterGroupName='blahpg',
    DBParameterGroupFamily='aurora5.6',
    Description='testing',
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': 'Testing'
        },
    ]
)

db_cluster = rds.create_db_cluster(
    AvailabilityZones=[
        'us-east-1a',
    ],
    BackupRetentionPeriod=1,
    DBClusterIdentifier='mydbcluster',
    DBClusterParameterGroupName='blahpg',
    DatabaseName='blah',
    Engine='aurora',
    EngineVersion='5.6.10a',
    MasterUserPassword='mypassword',
    MasterUsername='myuser',
    Port=3306,
    StorageEncrypted=True,
)

instance = rds.create_db_instance(
  DBInstanceIdentifier = 'moreblah',
  DBInstanceClass = 'db.r4.large',
  Engine='aurora',
  DBClusterIdentifier='mydbcluster' # this is where you put the cluster name
)
```